# NavBar / NavLink save "selected" React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

My question is this now,

in the following code

I have a NavBar that works properly

Here is the problem

when I click on the three 1st elements everything is fine, only when I click on "food" or "Shots" my NavBar starts again at 0 in display while I want it to stay focused on Shots or Softs

I hope I have correctly expressed my problem, thank you for your help

```
 import React from "react";
 import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
 import Slider from "react-slick";
 // Le css
 import './NavBar.scss'

 class NavBar extends React.Component {
   render() {
   const settings = {
   className: "sliderShadowBoxNavBar",
   centerMode: true,
   infinite: true,
   centerPadding: "60px",
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   speed: 500,
   rows: 1,
   slidesPerRow: 1,
   focusOnSelect: true,
};
return (
  <Slider {...settings}>
    <div className=''>
      <div className='containerNavBar'>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/Homescreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Bières</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/CocktailsHomeScreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Cocktails</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/VinHomeScreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Vins</p>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div className='containerNavBar'>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/PlanchesHomeScreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Food</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/AlcoolFortHomeScreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Spiritueux</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/ShotScreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Shots</p>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/SoftHomeScreen">
          <p className="textNavBar">Softs</p>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Slider>
   );
  }
 }
export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exact` on your NavLink

```
<NavLink exact activeClassName="selected" className="inactive" to="/PlanchesHomeScreen">
    <p className="textNavBar">Food</p>
</NavLink>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool